# FFMPEG reading keyframes

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, keyframe

I am trying to write a c++ program that would read key frames from the video file using ffmpeg.
So far I managed to get all the frames using `av_read_frame` where you sequentially read
frame by frame.

But I having some problems using `av_seek_frame` which (if I am correct) supposed to do the trick for keyframes.

```
int av_seek_frame(AVFormatContext *s, int stream_index, int64_t timestamp, int flags);
```

I have `FormatContext` but what are other correct arguments to sequentially get only all keyframes ?

Is there other function that I can use instead?

Thanks

EDIT: In `av_read_frame` i am getting AVPacket, which I can use to get frame data, but how I can get packet by using av_seek_frame ?

SOLUTION: OK there is a simple boolean value in AVFrame->key_frame. True if its a keyframe

Comment: What problems exactly are you having with `av_seek_frame()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[av_seek_frame](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/functions.html#av_seek_frame)** has the ability to seek to a certain timestamp in a video file. It takes 4 parameters: a pointer to the *AVFormatContext*, a *stream index*, the *timestamp* to seek to and *flags* to select the direction and seeking mode.

The function will then seek to the first key frame before the given timestamp.

[Check the documentation of that function for more information](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/functions.html#av_seek_frame).

Comment: From my experience it seeks to the first key frame After the given time stamp. And one should keep in mind that libav seeks in DTS, not PTS.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone here in the future, I've noticed `AVFrame->key_frame` to be unreliable at times (missing some keyframes).

A condition of `AVFrame->key_frame || AVFrame->pict_type == AVPictureType::AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I` has worked better for me.