# open source shot detection implementation?

Tags: video, opencv, computer-vision, multimedia

I am trying to implement a video retrieval system and I need to first extract key frames from a video, ideally I want to have a library for automatically detecting those key frames, one key frame from each shot. Bonus if I can configure which key frame to extract(first, middle, or last of the continuous frames in a shot).
Is there an open source implementation for this?

Comment: If you have the first frame of a shot then you know the last frame of the previous shot. And if you have first and last frames of shots then you can find a middle frame. You don't seem to be considering transitions, this will be your biggest challenge.

Comment: @koan I don't know the first/last frame of a shot, I'm actually trying to find shots in a video. I know how to extract frames from the video stream with opencv or other libraries once I know the boundary of shots.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not trivial. I doubt you will find a library function for doing this and if you did, it probably wouldn't get results suitable for your application.

Comment: You can try this one:
https://github.com/w495/python-video-shot-detector

Answer (score 5):

What you're after is called shot segmentation.  While it's a pretty active research area, I think you're unlikely to find any complete libraries that solve the problem for you out-of-the-box.  Your best option may be reading up on the topic, selecting an approach that best fits your requirements and coding it up yourself.

One approach is to calculate the chi-squared distance between the color histograms of adjacent frames.  When this distance rises above a user-specified threshold, you are at a shot boundary.  The approach is explained in [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=719786):

> A. Nagasaka and Y. Tanaka, "Automatic video indexing and full-video
>   search for object appearances", Journal of Information Processing
>   archive, Volume 15, Issue 2 (1992), Page 316

I've played around with it, with some success.  Notable failures are sudden light changes within a single shot (caused by camera flash, etc) and blending shot changes.

Once you know the shot boundaries, picking a keyframe from each shot will be trivial, as other people have pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The ffmpeg lib (included in openCV) can seek to a keyframe with av_seek_frame()

see [FFMPEG reading keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316407/ffmpeg-reading-keyframes)

Comment: The question is how to find key frames by shot detection because key frames are not available. Key frames in video coding are inserted for coding and not necessarily at shot cut boundaries (ideally they should be but you probably insert a *lot* more for navigation purposes)

Comment: @koan - if you want to extract a keyframe for each shot, the first step is to have a way of getting keyframes. Then you can decide which shot they are in

Comment: You would encode your video just to get candidate key frames ? Sounds inefficient and the candidates would be biased by rate-distortion metrics. Deciding which shot they are, well that's the original question isn't it ?

Comment: I thought the OP had the video files (in the retrieval system) and wanted to make thumbnails for easier recognition?

Comment: They could be stored as PNG, JPEG, MJPEG, etc. Key frames from a coding system would not necessarily include the first frames of any shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have as an input an uncompressed video, you can download the ffmpeg from [www.ffmpeg.org] and use this executable to decompress your video stream into its frames.

Subsequently, in order to detect your shot boundaries you have to extract some features from the video keyframes. An efficient technique for shot boundary detection is proposed in [MediaMixer Deliverable, D1.1.2](http://www.mediamixer.eu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/D1.1.2-final_Update1.pdf). In addition, in MediaMixer Webinars you can find the lecture [“Fragmenting your Media Assets meaningfully – media analysis for fragment detection and extraction”](http://videolectures.net/mediamixer_mezaris_media_assets/) where this shot-boundary detection implementation is presented, while you can also visit the MediaMixer demonstrator [http://www.mediamixer.eu/automatic-fragmentation-and-annotation-for-improved-access-to-lecture-videos/] where the results of video shot segmentation and concept detection are visualized.